# Launch Webkit Nightly in fullscreen mode

Tags: webkit, fullscreen

I am using Webkit Nightly because i'm working on some new HTML5 features. I would like to look at the application full screen, without the window chrome.

Other browsers have F11 and other buttons to go fullscreen, but webkit doesn't. Is there a way I can launch it in fullscreen mode?

Dennis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Webkit is a web content engine and its not a browser on its own. Anyway, which port of webkit are you referring to? GTK+? QT? EFL?

I just downloaded and compiled WebKit-r70098 (for GTK+) on my Ubuntu box following [this instructions](http://live.gnome.org/WebKitGtk). The demo browser (**GtkLauncher**) that comes with it creates a window of 800x600 (hardcoded in the code) and doesn't have a *fullscreen* feature.

Also, the pre-compiled binaries for Mac OS X that allows Safari to run on top of Webkit, don't offer native fullscreen capabilities. Currently there's no fullscreen without tweaking Safari configuration files or using 3rd party plugins (there are lots of them).

**EDIT:**

On Windows, *webkit.exe* also doesn't have fullscreen capabilities.

Comment: @Dennkster You forgot to state this important information on your question. I updated my answer.